# React - Split on string not having any effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I am trying to split a given text at each `\n` in order to put them on individual lines.
The problem is, in `React`, I am using the following code:

```
const details = property.details !== undefined
        ? property.details.split("\n").map((item, i) => {
            return <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
          })
        : "";
```

but there is no splitting made whatsoever. The returned array is simply the whole string. I tried the same string in the console of the browser and it works there.
Also, the `typeof` `property.details` is `string`.
What am I missing?

My render function for this component is:

```
 render() {
    const property = this.state.property;
    const details =
      property.details !== undefined
        ? property.details.split(/\r?\n/).map((item, i) => {
            return <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
          })
        : "";
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <div className="sweet-loading" style={{ marginTop: "120px" }}>
            <BarLoader
              sizeUnit={"px"}
              css={override}
              size={200}
              color={"#123abc"}
              loading={this.state.isLoading}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="container p-4" style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }}>
            <div className="row align-items-center">
              <div className="row display-inline p-3">
                <h3>{property.title}</h3>
                <h5 className="fontw-300">{property.zone}</h5>
                <h1 className="mt-5 price-font-presentation">
                  {property.sale_type} -{" "}
                  <strong>{property.price.toLocaleString()} EUR</strong>
                </h1>
              </div>
              <Carousel>
                {property.images.map(image => (
                  <img key={image.id} src={image.image} />
                ))}
              </Carousel>
              <div className="row p-3">
                <h3 className="border-bottom">Detalii</h3>
                {details}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Maybe I should mention that the information is taken with a django_rest api. Maybe there is a problem with returning \n in a string from there.

Comment: Well if that code works in the console, then clearly the problem must be somewhere in the surrounding code.

Comment: Please add the value of `property.details` to create a [mcve]

Comment: `The returned array is simply the whole string` how can it be the whole string? you are returning either array of JSX elements or an empty string. Are you sure you are checking `details` and not `property.details`?

Comment: An example which I tested would be:
"Property 1\n It is a luxurious apartment which has:\n 1 bedroom\n 2 kitchens\n 1balcnony".

The variable `details` is placed inside this block:
`
<div className="row p-3">
                <h3 className="border-bottom">Detalii</h3>
                {details}
              </div>
`

Comment: @Max I checked the value of the split with a console.log, that's how I know it is the whole string returned

Comment: @adiga, a valid example for `property.details` is:
"Property 1\n It is a luxurious apartment which has:\n 1 bedroom\n 2 kitchens\n 1balcnony"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might happen because client OS uses different symbols for new lines. Try this, it's multi-platform:

```
const details = property.details !== undefined
        ? property.details.split(/\r?\n/)
        : [];
```

EDIT:

typeof property.details is string because it's string. calling split on property.details returns array, but string remains to be string. 
From your updated code sample I can see that you are basically rendering details, which results in array transforming to string back again but without line seperators. 
Maybe you have to map it to paragraphs for example:

```
<h3 className="border-bottom">Detalii</h3>
{details.map(detail => <p>{detail}</p>)}
```

Also, try white-space: pre; css property as alternative

Comment: Tried this now, but no difference. I will post the whole render and maybe that will help

Comment: tried this updated method, but it still doesn't work. It put's a paragraph inside of which is another paragraph with the whole string.

Comment: @DavidBuzatu There's a hight chance that string doesn't have line seperators then.

Comment: The thing is, if I just copy-paste that strong from the console.log and I split it there, it is alright

Comment: Also, setting `white-space: pre-line;` on the paragraph makes no difference. Shouldn't this work as well?

Comment: @DavidBuzatu What happens if you put debug; after the line where map is performed? Is that correct that 'details' variable contains only one p, and then after running the same code in console it results in array of multiple paragraphs?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out! I've put the website back in development mode and checked for the values in the state and guess what? Django actually returned from the database the string with double `\\n`. I finally did it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this version:

```
const details = property.details !== undefined
  ? property.details.split('\r\n').map((item, i) =>
    <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
  )
  : '';
```

(It's the extra \r)

Comment: The OP says the code works when tested outside of the application context.

Comment: @scragar there is absoluely no difference between single and double quotes here.